# Data fetching from dynamic created table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to select rows from dynamic created tables i.e we have tables like web_analytics_mm_yy(ex: web_analytics_06_13, web_analytics_05_13, web_analytics_04_13 and so on)

- web_analytics ->common name for all tables
- mm_yy -> month_year( Will be created each month by cron)

I need to fetch Records from all the tables, we have like 1 million records in each table How we can acheive it?
is there any thing that can be done using mysql Query only or we can construct the SQL query in PHP?
and i want to know what is the best method to fetch data from multiple tables which are created dynamic Or is it better to change the DB design itself?

Thx ppl

Comment: Why would you put your data in seperate tables. Just add a field indicating the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to change the DB design to have a column for month/year. The system you have in place is a bad design.

Maybe a design similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `web_analytics` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`some_data_colum1` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`some_data_colum2` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`month` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`year`  varchar(2)
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

where month equals mm and year equals yy as you're using them now.

Comment: can u please suggest me on how we can re-design the existing database structure? also i think we can not put it column wise as per our existing system

Comment: That has been answered twice already: add an column for the month/year and read on Postgresql's table inheritance.

Comment: Cool Is it better to use Table partition? cos each month we will be having like a million records inserted. I want to know what will happen after a year of time like i will be having 1 billion + records in my db table and performance will be slow. so is better to partion the tables?

Comment: If we have month and year in same table, Don't we have a problem in fetching the records back? cos each month we will have 1 million records inserted. after couple of years data records will be huge and performance will be affected. So we have taut of splitting the table month wise and fetching the records

Comment: IF you want to do it via a partition doing a query like this will yield all of the tables that match that naming pattern: SHOW TABLES LIKE 'web_analytics_%';   Then you can loop through those results with some php and run your additional queries.

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want a slightly more performant database than mysql for that amount of data. I'd advise to take a look at http://www.postgresql.org. I have one running collection 50 to 80 million records per month in one table and doing queries on monthly subsets of that table.
Also take a look at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/ddl-inherit.html while you're at it. It could help you get your database design working.

Comment: Cool Is it better to use Table partition? cos each month we will be having like a million records inserted. I want to know what will happen after a year of time like i will be having 1 billion + records in my db table and performance will be slow. so is better to partion the tables?